What materials are best for creating a solar sail based of scientific factors
What materials are best to use for a solar sail? Since solar sails function through the transference of momentum from photons, a high reflectivity material would be best, no? Are there any scientific journals/experiments that examine different materials based of their reflectivity/emissivity that I could look at?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It would have to be light, and it would have to be reflective. There's very little scientific knowledge about solar sail dynamics right now because we haven't build many, so if you're worldbuilding just take a page from Netflix's adaptation of The Three-Body Problem series and make a nanofiber sail that's super-strong, super-reflective, and super-light. The tech is a little bit out there anyway.

A dielectric mirror is a good choice if you are propelling the sail with a high powered laser. Dielectric mirrors are over 99.99% reflective but only at a single wavelength. This allows them to withstand a high amount of laser power without melting. SailBeam is a design that takes advantage of this.
For regular solar sailing, powered by the Sun, aluminum on a polymer backing is a typical choice.

Awesome thank you! Are there any papers you know of that discuss the durability/reflectivity of the best materials
